# SQL query implementing AND functionality with PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using PHP with MySql. I need a query which should fetch me results according to my requirements.

I have a table property_features_table which has properties with some features.

In the front end I have a search functionality. When a user selects multiple features suppose 
balcony,wifi,2-bedroom etc., He should be shown with properties having ALL the features he selected.

But when I use the following code, I am getting results (properties) which has atleast one of the features.

```
$featuresString = implode("','",$features);
$featuresString = "'".$featuresString."'";
$query = " SELECT * FROM property_features_tbl WHERE property_features_tbl.feature_id in (".$featuresString.")";
```

$features is an array which contains user selected features.

I want to display properties which has all the features selected by the user. Help me in writing the query.

Comment: how you are storing features in database?

Comment: Please show us output of featuresString

Comment: @alok : the table has the following columns  primary_key,property_id,feature_id, 

same property can have many features and same feature can have many properties.

Comment: @AshReva here is what I get with $featuresString '81','55','82','56','83' (second time)

Comment: @raghuveer999  did  fired this query in database and checked?

Comment: @Hussain Tamboli 

This code gave me same result even.

$featuresString = implode(",",$features);
$query = " SELECT * FROM property_features_tbl WHERE property_features_tbl.feature_id in (".$featuresString.")";

Comment: How are you loading features in list? Is it coming from seperate table?

Comment: @AshReva , yes. The database gave me result which is showing all the properties with atleast one of the features

Comment: so you mean in database you fired this query and got required output
SELECT * FROM property_features_tbl WHERE property_features_tbl.feature_id in ('81','55','82','56','83' )

Comment: @AshReva features are from one table, properties are from another table.. 
in the query I am using 'property_features_tbl'

Comment: @AshReva yes! the same query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want the property ids, then something like this:-

```
<?php

$featuresString = implode("','",$features);
$featuresString = "'".$featuresString."'";
$feature_count = count($features);
$query = " SELECT property_id, COUNT(*) AS feature_count 
        FROM property_features_tbl 
        WHERE property_features_tbl.feature_id in (".$featuresString.")
        GROUP BY property_id
        HAVING feature_count = $feature_count";

?>
```

Comment: I dont think this query will make any difference because he says his query is working in database

Comment: The query will work, but will bring back every row where it has such a feature. Seems he wants those where the property has all those features (ie, a property could have 20 features, and will only be returned in all the required features are in that 20)

Comment: @AshReva no, My query is not working in database as I wanted.
It is showing me properties having atleast one of the features. I want properties having all the features.

Comment: @Kickstart, No doubt your query is working as per my requirement. But can you please explain me why my query didn't work and why did yours? Why COUNT(*) ? Why "GROUP BY property_id HAVING feature_count = $feature_count"? WHAT MADE THE DIFFERENCE?

Comment: You table would have multiple rows for a property, one for each feature. Your query was getting each of those rows where the feature was one you wanted. My version is finding all the rows for a property with the required features, using COUNT / GROUP BY to get a count of how many matching features each property has and then using HAVING to check that count is the same as the number of features you are looking for.